# Validate required model only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-validation

I'm using two models, Login & Signup Model in a View.

```
public class Login
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="User ID Required.")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Password Required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}

public class SignUp
{
    [Required (ErrorMessage ="User ID Required")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessage ="Name Required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessage ="Mail ID Required")]
    public string MailID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Password Required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Confirm Password Required")]
    [Compare (nameof(Password), ErrorMessage ="Password does not match")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }         
}
```

[image: Validates on Both Model]

when I click Login button, it validates both the models. How to validate the model separately?

Used following codes in controller

```
   public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Command, Login Login)
{
    if (Command == "SIGNUP")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Contact");
    }
    else
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValidField("USERID") && ModelState.IsValidField("PASSWORD"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("About");
        }               
    }
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml VIEW CODE:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="HolderForm">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Login</h4>
            <hr />

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.Login.UserID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "USER ID" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.Login.UserID,"", new {@class= "LoginValidation" } )
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.Login.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "PASSWORD" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.Login.Password,"", new { @class = "LoginValidation" })
                    @ViewBag.Posted
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                   @ViewBag.Posted
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" 
                            value="LOGIN"
                           id="btn_Login"
                           name="Command"
                            class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>SignUp</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"     })
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SignUp.UserID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "USER ID" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.SignUp.UserID,"", new {  @class = "LoginValidation" } )
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SignUp.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "NAME" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.SignUp.Name, "", new { @class = "LoginValidation" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SignUp.MailID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "MAIL ID" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.SignUp.MailID, "", new     { @class = "LoginValidation" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SignUp.Password, new {   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "PASSWORD", @type = "password" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.SignUp.Password, "", new { @class = "LoginValidation" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SignUp.ConfirmPassword, new {     htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "CONFIRM PASSWORD",     @type = "password" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o =>    o.SignUp.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "LoginValidation" })
                 </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type= "submit" value="SIGNUP"                               
                                 id="btn_Login"
                               name="Command"
                                class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>


}
```

Above code place on the view using two different model.

Please help and also suggest me where to learn ASP.NET (Beginner level)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you add `Login` and `SignUp` in one Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    ...
}
```

try this

```
<div class="HolderForm">
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Login</h4>
            <hr />

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(o => o.Login.UserID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "USER ID" } })<br>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.Login.UserID,"", new {@class= "LoginValidation" } )
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(o => o.Login.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "PASSWORD" } })<br>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.Login.Password,"", new { @class = "LoginValidation" })
                @ViewBag.Posted
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
               @ViewBag.Posted
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" 
                        value="LOGIN"
                       id="btn_Login"
                       name="Command"
                        class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>SignUp</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"     })
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SignUp.UserID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "USER ID" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.SignUp.UserID,"", new {  @class = "LoginValidation" } )
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SignUp.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "NAME" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.SignUp.Name, "", new { @class = "LoginValidation" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SignUp.MailID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "MAIL ID" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.SignUp.MailID, "", new     { @class = "LoginValidation" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SignUp.Password, new {   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "PASSWORD", @type = "password" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.SignUp.Password, "", new { @class = "LoginValidation" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.SignUp.ConfirmPassword, new {     htmlAttributes = new { @class = "LoginEntry", @placeholder = "CONFIRM PASSWORD",     @type = "password" } })<br>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o =>    o.SignUp.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "LoginValidation" })
                 </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type= "submit" value="SIGNUP"                               
                             id="btn_Login"
                           name="Command"
                            class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>


}
```

Comment: Yea, I added both models in the same form like you mentioned

Comment: Shady is saying that you added both the login and signup forms on one single form. You need to do it in two separate forms as the code given by him

Comment: Thank you @shady , It's working well.. Can you suggest me any links or  book to learn MVC